# How to make changes in system defined views?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, system-views

Can I make changes in system defined `views` like I want to add a `column` that will provide columns name which has been `foreign_key` applied ?

Like, changes in `sys.foreign_key_columns`.

Please provide me script or source.

Comment: @JeroenMostert you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @alroc: you're right, bad habits. Done.

Comment: @Deep you should accept the answer that Jeroen provided

Answer (score 12):

Microsoft will tell you that it isn't possible to change the definition of the system views. This is not true for the most part (after all, Microsoft themselves can do it with an upgrade) but it is very true that you, as a user, shouldn't be doing this, and the steps necessary for doing it are (deliberately) very complicated. If you did manage to succeed in changing the system views, your server is no longer covered by support, and you might not be able to install future updates. Basically, don't go this way.

As a more practical approach, consider wrapping the system views in views of your own and using those instead. If you want to make these views available in all new databases, you can add them to the `model` database.

For the specific case of a view that also includes the name(s) of the column(s) the foreign key is referring to, here's one view that will do the job (and is a friendlier view of foreign keys in general):

```
CREATE VIEW ext_foreign_keys AS
SELECT 
    OBJECT_NAME(constraint_object_id) AS foreign_key_name,
    OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) AS parent_table_name,
    COL_NAME(parent_object_id, parent_column_id) AS parent_column_name,
    OBJECT_NAME(referenced_object_id) AS referenced_table_name,
    COL_NAME(referenced_object_id, referenced_column_id) AS referenced_column_name
FROM sys.foreign_key_columns
```

If you need the data from `sys.foreign_keys` itself, join it up. I'm being lazy here by using the system functions `OBJECT_NAME` and `COL_NAME`; if you prefer, you can also join explicitly on `sys.tables` and `sys.columns`, though that's a lot more typing. You may want to do that anyway because [there are subtle issues with locking when using these functions](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQL/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=432497).

Comment: Thanks @Jeroen. Can you provide any source to make it happen?

Comment: @Deep: I updated the answer with a suggestion for the kind of view you may be after. If you rather mean the code/steps for changing the system views themselves, I could supply that, but I won't. It would be irresponsible to put something like that on Stack Overflow, even if accompanied by stern warnings. The few people who want to do this for legitimate reasons should also have the background knowledge required to figure it out themselves (or if not, they could make a separate question about it).